# Disable button and on button hover Show (diffrent)alert/error msg depending on status with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

```
<div class="col-md-12">       
<button type="button" class="btn-submit upload for-hover smooth-hover"           
ng-click="vm.onUpload($event, index, prod.ProductId)"                
ngf-select="vm.uploadAttachments($event, $files, $invalidFiles)" 
multiple accept="image/*,.pdf,*.doc,*.docx" 
ngf-capture="'camera'"  ngf-max-size="5MB" ng-
disabled="prod.Product_Status === ‘A’|| prod.Product_Status === ‘B’ 
|| prod.Product_Status === ‘C’ ">Upload Documents         
</button>     
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-fix on-hover col-xs-6 col-sm-6 
col-md-7 col-lg-7" ng-show="prod.Product_Status === ‘A’”>You are in 
A group</div>         
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-fix on-hover col-xs-6 col-sm-6 
col-md-7 col-lg-7" ng-show="prod.Product_Status === ‘B’”>You are in B 
group</div>         
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-fix on-hover col-xs-6 col-sm-6 
col-md-7 col-lg-7" ng-show="prod.Product_Status === ‘C’”>You are in C 
group</div>    
</div>


CSS---->
.on-hover {
  display: none;
}
.for-hover:hover + .on-hover {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I have one Upload Button, which is working fine with the ng-disabled condition, its disabling button on Conditions. I am trying to show error/alert msg when I have a certain status. Showing one fixed message working fine. but I want different messages depending on different status. It's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You are using curly quotes in your ng-disabled and ng-show attributes.
e.g. `=== ‘B’”`

Change them to straight quotes and your code works fine.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("controller", function($scope) {
    $scope.prod = {
      Product_Status: "C"
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller" class="col-md-12">
  <button type="button" class="btn-submit upload for-hover smooth-hover" ng-click="vm.onUpload($event, index, prod.ProductId)" ngf-select="vm.uploadAttachments($event, $files, $invalidFiles)" multiple accept="image/*,.pdf,*.doc,*.docx" ngf-capture="'camera'"
    ngf-max-size="5MB" ng-disabled="prod.Product_Status === 'A' || prod.Product_Status === 'B' || prod.Product_Status === 'C' ">Upload Documents        
</button>
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-fix on-hover col-xs-6 col-sm-6 
col-md-7 col-lg-7" ng-show="prod.Product_Status === 'A'">You are in A group</div>
  <div class=" alert alert-danger alert-fix on-hover col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-7 col-lg-7 " ng-show="prod.Product_Status==='B'">You are in B group
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-fix on-hover col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-7 col-lg-7 " ng-show="prod.Product_Status==='C'">You are in C group
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var isButtonDisabled = document.getElementById("myButton").disabled;
```

That can get button status as a boolean. Send your alert message based on that value.